# Appending to HTML through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Basically i'm having a HTML page built through a JS file by assigning to a variable then passing it to a HTML page.

```
this.printimg = function(){

  var myimgHTML ='<div>startup content</div>'; 
  var myimgHTML2="" ; 
  var myString="";

        if(this.getPreviewType()=="newView")
  {

    myString +="<a>Cover: </a><br><select id='sub1' style=' width:200px'>";
    myString +='<option value="'+ this.getTitle() +'">'+ this.getTitle() +'</option>';
    myString +="</select></select>";

  }

  else 
  {
  myString+='<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">';
  myString+='<div class="thumbnail">';
  myString+='<img style="width:230px" id="'+this.getId()+'" onclick=callToServer("'+this.getCurrent()+'_'+this.getId()+'") src="'+this.getImg()+'" alt="" border="0">';

  myString+='<div class="caption">';
  myString+='<h5 class= "text-center" ><name=""/>'+this.getTitle()+'</h5>';
  myString+='<p class= "text-center book_decs" style="color:#7F7F7F;">'+this.getDesc()+'</p>';
  myString+='</div></div></div></div>';
  }

  myimgHTML2=myString;
     if (this.getTheme() != null)
     {
     return myimgHTML;    
     }
     else if (this.getTheme() == null)
     {
      return myimgHTML2;
     }
   }

}
```

My problem is every time I'm calling my JS block it duplicate my select "dropdown menu" with my new values where it supposed to be like this:

```
Select 
- option 1
- option 2
- option 3
```

not like that:

```
Select
- option 1
Select 
- option 2
```

I tried straight forward methods like jQuery append or addHTML but was useless because it doesn't parse the HTML code which assigned as string.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post more of your js code.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code... Remove line 1 and 3 from loop, loop just through options....

Comment: There is no jQuery method `addHTML`. If you use `.html()` [you can quite easily add HTML as a string) to an element that replaces what's there already](http://jsfiddle.net/118o0o7y/1/).

Comment: @nevermind I need the looping because i'm printing an objects which have more than option like: books -> book1, book2, without looping I will have only the first object.

Comment: @Andy ok in my case I tried the following `$('#sub1').html('<option>someValue</option');`  but not result.

Comment: `myString +="</select></select>";`: note you are closing `select` twice here.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add "select" tag as static in html. and then append your "option" tag dynamically.

```
<select id="dynamic"></selecct>

<script>
   var options = '<option val="opt1"> Option Name </option>';
   options += '<option val="opt2"> Option Name 2</option>';

   $('#dynamic').html(''); // For clearing old data
   $('#dynamic').append(options);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks naveen, looks legit I will give it try.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript there is one line you wrote

```
 myString +="</select></select>";
```

It may be because of this. And as per my understanding it seems there is no need of two closing select tag.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't harm the code or the functionality.